# how to export SVG graph to pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, jquery-svg

I am using a [API](http://elycharts.com/examples) which render the line graph in SVG but I am not able to export it into PDF like other graph which render in HTML5 canvas

```
$(function() {
    // let's loop to build tooltips and x labels.
    var thelabels = new Array(30);
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        thelabels[i] = (i % 6 === 0) ? (i + 1) + " september" : "";
    }

    // build the chart using the "google analytics" template.
    $("#chart").chart({
        template: "raphael_analytics",
        labels: thelabels,
        values: values()
    });

    // start a loop that sets new data in the chart every 5 seconds.

});
```

Code is available in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JehdF/1236/)

while searching I got a link where I can export SVG graph to PDF but the demo what they provided it is not working and they used Perl script to export.

I wanted to export from client/browser to canvas image data

Edited

---

I have seen one more library in [github](https://github.com/CBiX/svgToPdf.js/) it allows you to download SVG to PDF from client side. But in the library they have used a object called `"RGBColor(fillColor)"` this throw an error like RGBColor is not defined so is there any library I need to include..???

Comment: Your fiddle link is invalid. Update it first !!!

Comment: @ Shreevardhan i edited my post please check it know.

Answer (score 1):

I had to convert graphs and pie charts to pdf and wound up using this third party package. It converts HTML to PDF. Just render graph and then pass the URL to the converter. It worked great. Its called [HiQPDf](http://www.hiqpdf.com/.)

Comment: i am sorry,  i am not allowed to send any of my graph data to go out side (specially internet)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can

1. print your webpage to `PDF`.
2. convert it using any script like [svgToPdf.js](https://github.com/CBiX/svgToPdf.js/).

To print as PDF, define a stylesheet for printing

```
@media print {
    body * { visibility: hidden; }
    #chart * { visibility: visible; }
    #chart { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; }
}
```

and call print using javascript

```
var chart = document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML,
    body = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = chart;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = body;
```

Comment: but " w.document.write($('#chart').html()); " code giving error like : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Comment: thanks for the replay, your idea work well in google chrome but not in other browsers

Comment: @RajeshHatwar Why not in other browsers, this is plain JavaScript and CSS, it should work in all modern browsers. Have you tested some. What are the results ?

Comment: ya i have tested, only in chrome it gives a option of saving file in PDF rest of the browser ask you to select printer to print the file

Comment: i seen one more library which allow to download SVG to PDF (like HTML2Canvas) but it is throwing error. can you see once "https://github.com/CBiX/svgToPdf.js/"

Answer (score 0):

This is not local but works fine. Using http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf to render your chart. I added their javascript and a button to download the PDF.

http://jsfiddle.net/JehdF/1237/

```
<button onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('chart',{pageWidth:'11in', pageHeight:'8.5in',render:'download'});">Get PDF</button>
<div id="chart" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
```

Use instructions are here: http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer it is working good and i just wanted to know like does converting SVG to PDF happen in client side or does it go to some URl and getting downloaded, because i am not allowed to send any of my graph data to go out side (specially internet)

Comment: i have seen it is sending chart data through ajax to this url: xepOnline.Formatter.xep_chandra_service,

Comment: i seen one more library which allow to download SVG to PDF (like HTML2Canvas) but it is throwing error. can you see once "https://github.com/CBiX/svgToPdf.js/blob/master/svgToPdf.js"

Comment: The CSS2PDF application uses an external server. If you do not want an external server you can always contact about implementing this in your own server (this is not a free option though as it uses licensed software from RenderX)